# Changing the language and region to arabic doesn't change layout direction

Tags: ios, ios-simulator

If I change the language or region to Arabic in the simulator, nothing happens. How can I fix this problem?

My app supports rtl and right-to-left-pseudocode in product>scheme does work and changes layout direction, but not if change it through settings in the simulator or in product>scheme.